# Divide dictionary values by another value in the same key in Python

Tags: python, dictionary, division

I am trying kind of a complicated operation here. I have a dictionary with the following structure:

```
'Paul ': [5, Counter({'i': 1, 'in': 1, 't': 1, 'fa': 1, 'cr': 1})],
'Lisa ': [4, Counter({'f': 3, 'bo': 1})], 
'Tracy ': [6, Counter({'sl': 3, 'fi': 1, 'an': 1, 'piz': 1})], '
'Maria': [2, Counter({'t': 2})]
```

What I need to do is to divide each of the Counter values for the first value in the key and append those values to the key. So that I would have something equivalent to:

```
'Paul': [5, Counter({'i': 1, 0.2, 'in': 1, 02, 't': 1, 02, 'cr': 1, 0.2})], 
  'Lisa ': [4, Counter({'f': 3, 0.75, 'bo': 1, 0.25})], 
  'Tracy ': [6, Counter({'sl': 3, 0.5, 'fi': 1, 0.16 'an': 1, 0.16 'piz': 1, 016 })], '
  'Maria': [2, Counter({'t': 2, 1})]
```

In which the values on counter on the first line are divide by 5, and by 4 on the second line, and so on. I have also tried to have two different dictionaries with the same key and divide each value of the first dictionary keys by the value of the second dictionary's key,

```
k: float(dict1[k])/dict2[k] for k in dict1.keys() & dict2.keys()}
```

but couldn't do it either. Is there a straightforward way to do this? I really thank you for your help!

Comment: You'll have to move away from using `Counter()` objects then; your nested values now are lists or tuples instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As noted by Martijn in comments, you would be able to use `Counter()` objects for your values, here is one way to do this that changes your values to dictionaries with tuples as values:

```
from collections import Counter

data = {'Paul ': [5, Counter({'i': 1, 'in': 1, 't': 1, 'fa': 1, 'cr': 1})],
        'Lisa ': [4, Counter({'f': 3, 'bo': 1})],
        'Tracy ': [6, Counter({'sl': 3, 'fi': 1, 'an': 1, 'piz': 1})],
        'Maria': [2, Counter({'t': 2})]}

for lst in data.values():
    lst[1] = {k: (lst[0], float(v)/lst[0]) for k, v in lst[1].items()}
```

Result:

```
>>> data
{'Lisa ': [4, {'bo': (4, 0.25), 'f': (4, 0.75)}],
 'Maria': [2, {'t': (2, 1.0)}],
 'Paul ': [5, {'cr': (5, 0.2), 'fa': (5, 0.2), 'i': (5, 0.2), 'in': (5, 0.2), 't': (5, 0.2)}],
 'Tracy ': [6, {'an': (6, 0.16666666666666666), 'fi': (6, 0.16666666666666666), 'piz': (6, 0.16666666666666666), 'sl': (6, 0.5)}]}
```

Note that this modifies your current dictionary in place, here is how you could create a new dictionary instead:

```
result = {}
for key, lst in data.items():
    result[key] = [lst[0], {k: (lst[0], float(v)/lst[0]) for k, v in lst[1].items()}]
```

Comment: @Jive. I don't know if I should open a new question for this, please let me know if it is the case. I was wondering if there is way to do this and have a slightly different outcome. Right now every pair in the nested dictionary contain the 1st value of the key and the outcome of the division. What I really need is that every value keep the value from the input plus the result of the division (for instance, for the very first line on the output, I would need Lisa: [4, bo: 1, 0.25; f: 3, 0.75) and not the current 'Lisa ': [4, {'bo': (4, 0.25), 'f': (4, 0.75)}. I really thank you for your help!

Comment: Sorry for the messy comment. I have figured it out! Thank you!